# replace image using gtk.image.set_from_file

Tags: image, widget, python-2.7, pygtk, glade

I'm trying to add and if needed by user, change the image from a widget in python.

I'm using Glade with gtk2+, python 2.7.3, and these is what I'm doing

```
image = gtk.Image()
image.set_from_file("MyImagePath.png")
image.show()

button = App.get_object('buttonExample')
button.add(image)
```

and this is what I get when try to change the image

> GtkWarning: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a
>   GtkAspectFrame, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkAspectFrame can only
>   contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type
>   GtkImage

The image is loaded correctly as expected, but if I change the input path for image, I wish I could change the button image, but this is not what I'm getting.

I tried to use gtk.Image.clear(), but it says I cannot use it on a button (maybe im just messing things around)

Is there a good way to load and reload images to a button?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to remove the old image from the button before adding a new one (the error message is pretty straightforward about this), or you could try changing the current image:

```
button.get_child().set_from_file("MyImagePath.png")
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. I used the clear in the image as you said and also cleaned the button image, as follows:

'App.get_object('buttonExample').remove(image)
image.clear()'

Answer (score 0):

This was exactly what I needed. I used the clear in the image as you said and also cleaned the button image, as follows:

```
App.get_object('buttonExample').remove(image)
image.clear()
```

Thank you very much for you help!