# PyGObject and Glade, dynamically changing icon of a button

Tags: python, glade, pygobject

how could i dynamically change the icon of a button created with glade?

**______________________** Last Edit **_________________________________________**

I'm trying this:

```
    self.button_waiting=self.builder.get_object('button_waiting')
    image=Gtk.Image()
    image.set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_ERROR, Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON)
    image.show()
    self.button_waiting.remove(image)
    self.button_waiting.add(image)
```

I get this error:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_remove: assertion `gtk_widget_get_parent (widget) 
==    GTK_WIDGET (container) || GTK_IS_ASSISTANT (container)' failed

(fresh_install:16299): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type 
GtkImage to a GtkButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkButton can only contain 
one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel
```

it seems like the error of the answer that I'm copying, but doing what he did is not working for me.

I read that it is possible to put images on labels, how can i get the name of the label of the button made in glade?

following this answer:
[replace image using gtk.image.set_from_file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461285/replace-image-using-gtk-image-set-from-file)

**___________________** Original Question **_________________________________**
I'm trying this:

```
    self.button_waiting=self.builder.get_object('button_waiting')
    self.button_waiting.set_label("Cancel")
    image=Gtk.Image.set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_ERROR, Gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)
    image.show()
    self.button_waiting.image.clear()
    self.button_waiting.add(image)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'ICON_SIZE_BUTTON'
```

But i found GTK_ICON_SIZE_BUTTON on the reference manual >.<

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you are using PyGObject (GTK+ 3.x) based on the fact that you're `Gtk` instead of `gtk`. If that's the case, then you should use `Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON` rather than `Gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON`.

This is because the [GObject Introspection](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GObjectIntrospection?action=show&redirect=GObjectIntrospection) will put the constants into a namespace rather than the long constants we see in the C source code. It's generally pretty easy to figure it out based on the context.

Comment: Yep! you are right, i think that now I'll be able make better researches and understand better the reference manual.  I'm still getting an error, TypeError: unbound method set_from_stock() must be called with Image instance as first argument (got str instance instead) I'm trying to find out what it is.         By the way, i want to thank you for your Glade tutorial :)

Comment: That error sounds like you aren't calling set_from_stock() on a Gtk.Image instance. It should be something like: image = Gtk.Image(); image.set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_NEW, Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON);

Comment: That's what i supposed, i did: image=Gtk.Image ;
  image.set_from_stock(Gtk.STOCK_DIALOG_ERROR, Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON)