# Change images at runtime with Glade3/Python3 Gtk

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, gtk3, glade

How can I change an image at runtime with Glade?

I'm trying to prompt a "refresh" of an image in my GUI when a button is pressed.  The idea is that my handler will do some work on the image, and once it is complete, the image will load in the new image data from file.

I've been working from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461285/replace-image-using-gtk-image-set-from-file#11500817) to try and accomplish this, but with no success.

Below is a stripped-down version of what I am working with.  I am simply trying to load a second image whenever the button is pressed.  I have also tried creating a new PixBuf with the image filepath, assigning it to the image widget, and adding that back to the parent.

I have verified that the builder is retrieving the image correctly.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GdkPixbuf

STREETMAP       = "/home/testrun/testing/output.png"
RADARMAP        = "/home/testrun/testing/radar.png"

# The glade file to load widgets from
GLADEFILE       = "slideshow.glade"

def get_builder(filename):
    builder = Gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file(filename)
    return builder

class mapWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.builder     = get_builder(GLADEFILE)
        self.toggle      = 1

        # Define signal mappings for builder
        self.handlers = {
            "quit"          :self.quit,
            "change"        :self.change
        }

        self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
        self.builder.connect_signals(self.handlers)

    def quit(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit(*args)

    def change(self, button):
        image_file = ""
        if(1 == self.toggle):
            self.toggle = 0
            image_file = RADARMAP
        else:
            self.toggle = 1
            image_file = STREETMAP

        print("Changing image to %s" % image_file)
        builder = get_builder(GLADEFILE)
        mapImg = builder.get_object("image1")
        parent = builder.get_object("box1")
        parent.remove(mapImg)
        mapImg.clear()
        mapImg.set_from_file(image_file)
        parent.add(mapImg)
        mapImg.show()
        self.window.show_all()
        print("Image rendered")

myWindow = mapWindow()
myWindow.window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

And here is my .glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <signal name="delete-event" handler="quit" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkImage" id="image1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="pixbuf">radar.png</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Change</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <signal name="pressed" handler="change" swapped="no"/>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the glade widgets from the method `change()` to the `__init__()` method and let them be object properties, no need to always retrieve the same widget.

Once you have it as a property, then on the `change` callback method just change the image. Notice that if the image sizes differ, the window will readjust it's size if the second image is bigger but won't shrink if smaller.

Check the code between the hash lines:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.builder     = get_builder(GLADEFILE)
    ...
    #############################################################
    self.window = self.builder.get_object("window1")
    self.mapImg = self.builder.get_object("image1")
    self.parent = self.builder.get_object("box1")
    self.builder.connect_signals(self.handlers)
    self.window.show_all()
    #############################################################
    ...
    ...
    ...
def change(self, button):
    image_file = ""
    if(1 == self.toggle):
        self.toggle = 0
        image_file = RADARMAP
    else:
        self.toggle = 1
        image_file = STREETMAP

    print("Changing image to %s" % image_file)
    #############################################################
    self.mapImg.set_from_file(image_file)
    #############################################################
    print("Image rendered")
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.As a quick clarification, was fetching the builder specifically the problem?

Comment: @Onofog Yes, When you use GTkBuilder it instantiates the widgets which means you had everything duplicated but you only show'ed one. Basically you where also correct although not optimized, problem was that you didnt update the correct, let's say, parent... is like you have two windows but the one you were changing was not being shown.

Comment: @Onofog, not duplicated... everytime you clicked the button you were creating more windows, with boxes and images.. but you always did self.window.show_all(), so they were always invisible. Also, you just need to do show_all() only once, normally.

Comment: @Onofog To put it simply: If you keep a reference to builder, every time you get a widget, it will be the same. If you create many GtkBuilder objects even from the same file, you will have different widgets